# TabView doesn't show the next N SelectionValue where SelectionValue == UInt

Tags: swift, swiftui, tabview, uint

The code below doesn't show `Text("Second View")`, because `private var selection: UInt`.

```swift
struct TabMenu: View {
    @State private var selection: UInt = 0

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection){
            Text("First View")
                .font(.title)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "house")
                    Text("Main")
            }
            .tag(0)

            Text("Second View")
                .font(.title)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "gear")
                    Text("Preferences")
            }
            .tag(1)
        }
    }
}
```

In sources of TabView, I found this:

```swift
extension TabView where SelectionValue == Int {

    @available(watchOS, unavailable)
    public init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content)
}
```

How I can create a custom view where `SelectionValue == Uint` ?

```swift
where SelectionValue == Uint
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selection must be the same type as tag is (by default both are Int).

Here is a solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
struct TabMenu: View {
    @State private var selection: UInt = 0

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection){
            Text("First View")
                .font(.title)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "house")
                    Text("Main")
            }
            .tag(UInt(0))

            Text("Second View")
                .font(.title)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "gear")
                    Text("Preferences")
            }
            .tag(UInt(1))
        }
    }
}
```